# How to display code snippet in textview?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I'm trying to display code snippet in a textview.But i cannot make long text line auto scrollable horizontally  in textview.

code:

```
    TextView code = new TextView(getActivity());
    TableRow.LayoutParams paramsExample = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    code.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
    code.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    code.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    code.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,12);
    code.setClickable(true);
    code.setLayoutParams(paramsExample);
    setCode(code, R.raw.codesnippet);
    ll.addView(code);
```

I'm creating this textview in a fragment.fragment_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_ll"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

and i am starting this fragment in an activity in 
coordinatorlayout > nestedscrollview > linearlayout(fragment container)

each one's width size is "match parent"

this is setcode method:

```
   public void setCode(TextView tv, int rawId) {
    Resources res = getResources();
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            res.openRawResource(rawId)));
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Spanned spannedCode = Html.fromHtml(sb.toString());
    tv.setText(spannedCode);
}
```

i got that code snippet (codesnippet.txt) from vim:toHtml.

but it does not scroll horizontally.What should i do to make it auto scrollable horizontally like a webview ?

output with above code:
[image]

after HorizontalScrollView and code.setHorizontallyScrolling(true):
[image]

 Horizontal scrolling works fine in single line.I need to display code snippet as a block.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it right, but maybe you don't have newlines in your text?
usually it is \n but sinve you are using Html.fromHtml then you should have <br> for newline. And with that use the code.setHorizontallyScrolling and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your `TextView` should be inside a `HorizontalScrollView` like the following:

```
<HorizontalScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="Horizontal scroll view"/>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: i already tried this before.But it shows in single line not multi line.Also i added tv.setSingleLine(false ) after that problem.but still shows single line

Comment: added screenshots  about this answer